# Cuál es la diferencia entre print y return?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def multiply(m=8, n=90):
        return m*n

multiply()

    
def sum(a=40, b=90):
    print(a+b)

sum()
```

Comment: print imprime en la consola mientras que return *devuelve* el valor. Prueba a hacer `print(multiply()` y `print(sum())` y lo verás.

Answer (score 4):

- La función **print ()** imprime el mensaje especificado en la pantalla u otro dispositivo de salida estándar.
- La declaración de Python **return** es una declaración especial que puede usar dentro de una función o método para enviar el resultado de la función a la persona que llama

```
def hola():
 print("Hola mundo")

hola()
Salida por consola: Hola mundo

def suma():
 return 1+2

a = suma()
print(a)
Salida por consola: 3
```

[Mas información y ejemplos](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#returning-vs-printing)